# Compiling libapache2-svn for Apache 2.4.4

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu-12.04

I want to use Apache 2.4.4 with SVN on Ubuntu server 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). But when I use

```
apt-get install libapache2-svn
```

I get the following dependencies error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-svn : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed
```

Googling around I got some suggestion about compiling from source by hand. I don't know how to do that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two solutions:

1. Follow the instructions in this [Server Fault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/513399/debian-after-upgrade-apache-to-2-4-4-libapache2-svn-wont-work).

   *Note: Create another user if you're using a root account on the server.
2. I've asked Ondřej Surý on Launchpad to add Subversion to his Apache PPA. You can add [Ondřej Surý's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2) to perform a normal update/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You did ask Ondrej to include Subversion in his PPA launchpad. But I couldn't install the libapache2-svn package after adding Ondrej's PPA.

Somehow the instructions provided for compiling didn't work for me so here's an alternative way to get it working.

Reference:
(https://askubuntu.com/questions/312568/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-8-binary)

WANDisco has Subversion 1.8 for Ubuntu then:

```
    sudo sh -c 'echo "# WANdisco Open Source Repo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/WANdisco.list'
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu precise svn18" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/WANdisco.list'
    wget -q http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo apt-get update
```

After that:

```
apt-cache show subversion | grep '^Version:'
```

And then you should be good to install normally:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn
```